# Bootstrap slideshow using arrows to navigate

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow, carousel

I am working with bootstrap at the moment for the first time.
I was wondering if it is possible to create some sort of carousel gallery or if there are any templates out there that suits my needs.

I want something that has an image showing at the top then the description of that image in a separate div below.
The slideshow will show three at a time and the user can use left and right arrows to navigate through the images and descriptions.
I also want it to be responsive to work on smaller devices.

I thought this task would be pretty easy but I am finding it hard to find any resources online to help.

Maybe something with similar functionality to this example: http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified

Comment: Follow this link...maybe it help - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carouse or this - https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-3-carousel-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

This would be fairly easy to do using bootstrap's carousel (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

Your carousel items do not have to be images, they can be divs containing any elements you want. So for example, the first carousel item can look like this:

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="image1" alt="..." class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="help-block text-center">Caption for image 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="image1" alt="..." class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="help-block text-center">Caption for image 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <img src="image3" alt="..." class="img-responsive" />
        <p class="help-block text-center">Caption for image 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then your next item can contain images/captions numbers 4, 5 and 6, and so on..

Just make sure your images have the "img-responsive" class, and they should scale down nicely with the entire carousel.

Bootstrap's carousel example is pretty straightforward, so you can check the site to see how to add the navigation arrows, but it looks like this:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
```